# Obtain count for duplicates in two tables oracle sql

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a database and I will primarily focus on two table.  Table 1 has emp_id as primary key

Table 1 store access info for each employee.  I am tasked to count how many time an employee goes into a room..

Table 1

```
emp_id  time_in time_out, other columns etc

1111    3:00        3.30     
2222    1:00        1:10
3333    2:00        2:45
4444    7:00        5:00
```

table 2

sequence_no, emp_id, time, access type, other columns etc

Table 2 has multiple entries of enties

```
sequence_no, emp_id, time, access type

10000       1111     3:00   granted
10221       1111     3:23   granted
19911       2222      x
12122       1111      x
23232       3333
```

I have written sQl query that display joins the two tables,
but at the moment I am trying to add a column that either sums total entries (due to the sequence number, my query is returning multiple rows)

```
select e.emp_id,a.sequence_no,count(sequence_no) from employee, access a where e.emp_id = a.emp_id 
group by e.emp_id having count t(1) > 1
```

output should look like

```
emp_id, sequence number, time in/out , total_counts

1111    10000              3:30         5
1111    12122              3:30         5
2222    19911              2:20         19
```

within the results, I need the sequence number which will cause duplicate emp_id, but the total for each ID should be the same accross;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to group anything:

```
select 
  e.emp_id,
  a.sequence_no,
  count(sequence_no) over (partition by e.emp_id) as total_counts
from employee, access a 
where e.emp_id = a.emp_id
```

If you want to filter those emps with less than two entries:

```
select * 
from 
(
    select 
      e.emp_id,
      a.sequence_no,
      count(sequence_no) over (partition by e.emp_id) as total_counts
    from employee, access a 
    where e.emp_id = a.emp_id 
)
where total_counts >= 2;
```

If you want to group by emp, in Oracle(I don't know if the syntax is ok in sqlserver) you can use `keep`:

```
select 
  e.emp_id, 
  max(a.sequence_no) keep (dense_rank first order by time desc), --last sequence
  count(sequence_no) 
from employee, access a 
where e.emp_id = a.emp_id 
group by e.emp_id 
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: thanks, in my query I had the over (partition by) statement wrong. It was counting each individual row...This is was I had ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY e.emp_id ORDER BY  e.emp_id DESC) AS COUNT. Thanks for your input.